# AWS cloudformation json script to run bash script on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've created a cloudformation script that creates an ec2 instance, a few volumes upon other features. When the ec2 instance has been initialised I want it to run a bash script automatically to mount a volume created in the script (not the root volume) to /var/www/vhosts. But at the moment it creates the directory so I know its running the bash script but doesn't successfully execute the other commands. Here is my cloudformation script. When I run the 3 commands listed below separately when ssh to the ec2 instance they work fine and the volume has been mounted to the correct location.

```
    "Ec2Instance": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": {
      "Ref": "ImageIdentification"
    },
    "AvailabilityZone" : "eu-west-1a",
    "InstanceType": {
      "Ref": "InstanceType"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIds" : [
       {
         "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
       }
    ],
    "DisableApiTermination" : "true",
    "KeyName": {
      "Ref": "keyPairName"
    },
    "Tags" : [
      {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : { "Ref" : "EC2InstanceName"}}
    ],
    "UserData" : {"Fn::Base64" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [
     "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
      "sudo mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts\n",
      "sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdh\n",
      "sudo mount /dev/xvdh /var/www/vhosts\n"
    ]]}}
  }
},
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The service that runs the user-data script is called `cloud-init`. Check the cloud-init log on the server to see what the issue is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691867/where-to-find-logs-for-a-cloud-init-user-data-script

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your help. That worked perfectly for troubleshooting. For anyone who's reading this I ran the command 'vim /var/log/cloud-init-output.log' to view the log. I also added a sleep command to the bash script and the volume property to the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

To run the bash script in CloudFormation you need to specify the remote link in the user data section or write down the commands one by one in the user data.

```
Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: test
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      cd /var/tmp
      wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/installer/cloudformation/install.sh
      sudo bash /var/tmp/install.sh 4  '${CORE.PrivateIp}'
```